# ADO.NET - DataRead Error

Tags: c#, ado.net, datareader, dataadapter

I am trying to display data from a column in my database onto my rich textbox, but I am getting mixed up between DataSet and DataReader - I know the majority of the code below is correct, I just get two lines containing errors, and I'm not sure why:

```
// Create a connection string
            string ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\\Documents and Settings\\Harley\\Desktop\\Test.accdb");
            string SQL = "SELECT * FROM Paragraph";

            // create a connection object
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            // Create a command object
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
            conn.Open();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt); //ERROR

            // Call ExecuteReader to return a DataReader
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            foreach(DataRow reader in dsRtn) //ERROR
            {
                richTextBox = richTextBox.Text + reader[0].ToString();
            }

            //Release resources
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your snippets has an issue.

For the Data Adapter implementation you provided this:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
        conn.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt); //ERROR
```

You are not associating your SqlCommand object with your DataAdapter so it has no idea how to fill your DataTable.

As for your Data Reader implementation,

```
        // Call ExecuteReader to return a DataReader
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        foreach(DataRow reader in dsRtn) //ERROR
        {
            richTextBox = richTextBox.Text + reader[0].ToString();
        }
```

you are using the DataReader incorrectly try this:

```
        // Call ExecuteReader to return a DataReader
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while( reader.Read() )
        {
            richTextBox = richTextBox.Text + reader[0].ToString();
        }
```